# Two questions about Banach space theory.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm recently studying Banach space theory, and get stuck in following two questions. Any feedback or reference would be appreciated.

1. We know that $\ell^\infty$ is not separable, and $c_0$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$. However, this would imply $(\ell^\infty)^*\subseteq (c_0)^*\simeq\ell^1$.Therefore, $(\ell^\infty)^*$ is separable. We know a Banach space is separable if its dual is separable, so $\ell^\infty$ is separable, which is apparently wrong. There must be something wrong in my argument, but I just couldn't find it.
2. If a separable Banach space $X$ has a separable dual, why $X$ cannot contain a copy of $\ell^1$?(Comes from the proof for the theorem that a Banach space X possesses a shrinking basis if and only if it does not contain  copy of $\ell^1$.)

Once again, any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: BTW. It was conjectured that every separable Banach space has a Schauder basis, but in the latter 20th century this was shown to be false.... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ has a subspace $Y$ which is isomorphic to $\ell_1$ then $Y^*$ is isomorphic to $\ell_1^*=\ell_{\infty}.$

Now $\ell_{\infty}$ has an uncountable subset $G$ such that $\|g_1-g_2\|=1$ for any unequal $g_1,g_2\in G.$ And  each $g\in G$ can be extended to a member of $X^*.$ So for each $g\in G,$ choose $\phi(g)\in X^*$ with $\phi(g)|_Y=g.$   Now if $g_1,g_2$ are unequal members of $G$ then

$\|\phi(g_1)-\phi(g_2)\|=$ $\sup \{|\phi(g_1)(x)-\phi(g_2)(x)|: x\in X\land \|x\|=1\}\ge$

$\ge \sup \{|\phi(g_1)(x)-\phi(g_2)(x)|:x\in Y\land\|x\|=1\} =$ $\|g_1-g_2\|=1.$

Or we could just observe that if $\psi(f)=f|_Y$ for $f\in X^*$ then $\psi:X^*\to Y^*$ is continuous, and the Hahn-Banach theorem implies $\psi$ is a surjection. And observe that a continuous image of a separable space is separable, so if $X^*$ were separable then $Y^*$ would be separable.

Answer (score 2):

For Q1: If $X\subset Y$ but $X$ is *not* dense in $Y$, then we don't have $Y^*\subset X^*$. Think of $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}^2$ for example.

Comment: $X=\{0\}, Y=\mathbb  R$ is  a simpler example.

Comment: I suspect the proposer got the mistaken idea that $c_0\subset \ell_{\infty}$ implies $ \ell_{\infty}^*\subset c_0^*$ from the Hahn-Banach Theorem: If $f\in c_0^*$ then $f$ can be extended to $f'\in \ell_{\infty}^*$ with $\|f\|=\|f'|\|.$ However there generally are many such extensions